# How to use Angular ng-click function to only add 1

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have this function in my Angular controller but I only want the user to be able to add 1 heart, and if they click again, it would remove the heart. How can this be accomplished?

```
$scope.activeClass = false;

$scope.addHeart = function(post){

    post.hearts += 1;

    $scope.activeClass = !$scope.activeClass;

};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$scope.activeClass = false;

$scope.addHeart = function(post){

    $scope.activeClass ? post.hearts += 1 : post.hearts -= 1;

    $scope.activeClass = !$scope.activeClass;

};
```

Comment: Perfect! I was trying all kinds of crazy if/else statements but now looking at this I fee like an idiot.